# Rewrite rule doesn't change the browser url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following problem:
current url:
mysite.com/Category.php?Category=Category name

Want it to show up in the browser as follows:
mysite.com/Category name

I have the following in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ Category.php?Category=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ Category.php?Category=$1
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything

Thanks for looking

Current rules:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^musite1.co.uk$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.co\.uk\/$1" [R=301,L] #5311a623b538f
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk$
rewriterule ^Pianoshop\/detailed_page\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.co\.uk\/product\.php$1" [R=301,L] #5310700a7e477
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk$
rewriterule ^Pianoshop\/index_blog\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.co\.uk\/news\.php$1" [R=301,L] #53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried that and it gave me a 404 error

Comment: Which URL did give 404 to you? What is location of this .htaccess and are there other rules too?

Comment: there are some other rewrite rules in there the page was rewritten so the url was my site/Category name however that gave the 404 error

Comment: ok then post your current rules in question and I need to know for which URL you are getting 404? Is this some CMC/PHP framework?

Comment: All my pages are made with php

Comment: Read my previous 2 comments again and see if you have answered my repeated question.

Comment: the .htaccess is in the webroot. I do have multiple domain names on the server not sure if that make a difference. The 404 resulted from my site.co.uk/Category name. Or really the my site.co.uk/Category.php?Category=Categoryname (so the redirect worked only the right page wasn't displayed this showed the 404 error. Hope that is what you meant.

Comment: Yes this helps but I want you to provide all of your existing rules in your question so that I can figure out conflicting rules.

Comment: These are all the rules I've got please see amended question

Comment: I am every so sorry to be asking you again. I wanted to add another rewrite rule in a similar way to the .htaccess file however this doesn't work. Do I need to add any thing more to the acces as I thought the other page would work the same. I want to change an x.php?id=34-some-name (these are dynamic) to just /34-some-name in a same way as the category page. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: It should work on similar lines. But remember `/abc` can either be internally written to `/Category.php` OR `/x.php` but NOT both. Hope you understand my point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to add the following to the rewrite rule for the product:RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/p/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA], as I hope that is what you meant. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Since comments have gone very long on this thread I will comment on your new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod rewrite enabled ?

Your .htaccess should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1
```